# C++ string not printed

Tags: c++, string

I have the next code:

```
void addContent ( const std::string& message ) {
   std::string newMessage;

   for ( int i = 0, remainder = textCapacity - currentText; i < remainder; i++ ) {
      newMessage[i] = message[i];
      std::cout << newMessage; //here nothing is printed
   }
}
```

But nothing is printed.

Only if I change `newMessage` to `newMessage[i]` everything is good. And I dont undestand why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [No console output on cout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591915/no-console-output-on-cout)

Comment: Try `std::cout << newMessage << "\n"`

Comment: `newMessage` is an empty string. To see the error put in a try/catch block.

Comment: @Nobody: not a duplicate of that, as it's not a case of buffering. It's a case of invalid memory access and an empty string.

Comment: "everything is good" - no it isn't. Now you're writing to invalid memory, then reading back what you've just written. Maybe it will appear to work; maybe it will crash; maybe it will corrupt something unrelated and cause hideously intractible bugs.

Comment: You probably want to [append](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator+=/)

Comment: I see that I created an empty string! In that case how I can copy a part of one string to another string?

Answer (score 0):

`newMessage` is an empty `std::string`.  Doing `[i]` to it is accessing invalid memory. The string is always empty, and you're just writing to invalid memory. That's a recipe for disaster, and you're (un)lucky it's not crashing on you.

I'm not sure what `message[i]` is, but you probably want `newMessage[i]` = `message[i]`. But you might as well skip the temporary `newMessage` variable and just print out `message[i]` itself.

Answer (score 0):

`newMessage` is an empty string, so nothing will be printed. Also, `std::cout` is buffered, so in order to flush the buffer you should call `std::endl` or `std::flush`

Answer (score 0):

I would rather change from this:

```
newMessage[i] = message[i];
```

to this:

```
newMessage += message[i];
```

And when printing:

```
std::cout << newMessage<<std::endl;
```

Using [i] on empty string is looking for trouble because your entering invalid out of bound memory. Sometimes it will do nothing sometimes your program will crash.

Answer (score 0):

As Cornstalks said, you have an out-of-bounds access.

More importantly, the code is way too complex for the task. Don't use a manual loop to partially copy one `std::string` to another. To copy a part of `message` to `newMessage`, use `substr` on `message` and assign:

```
newMessage = message.substr(from_index, number_of_chars);
```

or the iterator-based stuff:

```
std::string newMessage(message.begin() + from_index, message.begin() + to_index);
```

The latter is more efficient. So you want

```
std::string newMessage(message.begin(), message.begin() + (textCapacity - currentText));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using that string as `newMessage[i]` is implying that it an array of strings. Replace that line with `std::string newMessage[textCapacity];`.